# How to calculate a summary value for parent in Treelist

Tags: c#

The situation is the following:

I have a treelist where items have 4 fields: Primary Key, Parent Key, Description and a numeric value.
If the Parent Key is equal to 0 then it's a root.
I have the numeric value only for child items and I need to calculate a summary value for each parent till the root.

How can I do this?

Comment: You have described your requirement, even if it's still unclear if it's a sql question or C#. But what have you tried, what's the issue at all?

Comment: What do you mean by *calculate a summary value for each parent till the root*?

Comment: @TimSchmelter Tag says c#. However I don't know how to do it. I tried with nested foreach loops but without success, that's why I asked how can I do this.

Comment: @ArDevTeam: we can only fix code that we can see. Apart from that, such tasks should be done in the database.

Comment: @AlexJolig Question updated. Sorry, it wasn't clear.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I have no code because I don't know how to do it. I'm stuck in the first foreach that calculate the first parent and I don't know how to go on.

Comment: @ArDevTeam: it would still help if we could see it. Otherwise it's far too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Using recursion:

```
public int SumRecursive(ClassWithParent item, int childSum) {
    var currentSum = childSum + item.NumericValue;

    if (item.ParentKey == 0) {
        // finished recursion
        return currentSum;
    }
    else {
         // retrieve parrent from DB and call recursivly
         var parent = DbContext.ClassWithParent.Find(item.ParentKey);
         return SumRecursive(parent, currentSum);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if first `item` is **root** item?

Comment: Then ParentKey would be `0` and `item.NumericValue` would be returned. (For the initial call, pass `childSum` as `0`.)